# fscanf() is not getting the data in file handling in VSTS

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have the following code

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <process.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char text[5];
    int age;
    fp=fopen("E:\Text1.txt","w+");
    printf("Enter text here and Enter Age :");
    scanf("%s %d",text,&age);
    fprintf(fp,"%s %d",text,age);


    printf("Entered Text and Age is :\n");
    fscanf(fp,"%s %d",text,&age);
    printf("Text=%s Age=%d",text,age);
    fclose(fp);
    getche();
}
```

I have a problem with fscanf function. The data is not displayed in the output .When i try to debug the code , it throws an error stating "unhandled exception .... Access violation"
at this code

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %d",text,&age);
```

To my knowledge , i think the VSTS has no access to get the file location. i have created the file in the E Drive. Please help me how to solve my problem.

Comment: You stripped the error checking out of all of this code (since there is *none*) for brevity when you posted it, right? .. *right* ?

Comment: did i missed anything?

Comment: Apparently, yes. **Check your API calls for error results**.

Answer (score 1):

you have two problems

first is the path `"E:\Text1.txt"=>"E:\\Text1.txt"`

sec is `fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","w+");` just open that file for write

and you want to read from that file then you should open it for read with

`fp=fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","r");`

since u opened it with `w+` u can use

```
fseek(fp,0,0);
```

to make the point to the start of the file

```
   # include <stdio.h>
    # include <conio.h>
    # include <process.h>

    void main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char text[5];
        int age;
        fp=fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","w+");
        printf("Enter text here and Enter Age :");
        scanf("%s %d",text,&age);
        fprintf(fp,"%s %d",text,age);
        fclose(fp);

        fp=fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","r");
        printf("Entered Text and Age is :\n");
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d",text,&age);
        printf("Text=%s Age=%d",text,age);
        fclose(fp);
        getche();
    }
```

another version is

```
   # include <stdio.h>
    # include <conio.h>
    # include <process.h>

    void main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char text[5];
        int age;
        fp=fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","w+");
        printf("Enter text here and Enter Age :");
        scanf("%s %d",text,&age);
        fprintf(fp,"%s %d",text,age);

        fseek(fp,0,0);

        printf("Entered Text and Age is :\n");
        fscanf(fp,"%s %d",text,&age);
        printf("Text=%s Age=%d",text,age);
        fclose(fp);
        getche();
    }
```

Comment: It *is* opened for write purposely on the first fopen. It is never read-from, only written-to, in the first block. It is the closed and reopened in read-mode fro pulling the written data back out.

Comment: I don't know if this is different with VSTS but, initially, "w+" mode should allow you to write and read.

Comment: and also you can use fseek(fp,0,0);

Comment: @user3027039 Is better that you use `rewind` (check my update) instead of closing and opening again because of performance impact.

Comment: +1 You're correct on the open-mode. [`fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) confirms it.

Answer (score 0):

You file path is not properly formated, you should double backslash it:

```
fp=fopen("E:\\Text1.txt","w+");
```

Edit: After checking, I realized that your problem should be actually related to position indicator, once you write, it's set at the end of the file and you should rewind it:

```
fprintf(fp,"%s %d",text,age);
rewind(fp);
```

Comment: Even i use double backslash , the data is not outputed. :(